# Rails: How to check what is cached for a specific page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

So on my ecommerce site I have a bunch of categories for my products

I have an issue where on my production site, 2 of these category#show pages that show a bunch of products don't load the product partials properly. Everything else is fine, pagination is good (and displays '1-15 products out of 86'), but no products actually show up on the page.

I'm guessing this is a caching issue? How would I actually look inside of `Rails.cache` to see what contents are cached on that specific `/category/2/show/` page? Something like `Rails.cache("/category/2/show/")` (conceptually).

My other categories are showing properly (they're handled by the same controller#action) so that's why I'm thinking it's a caching issue. Plus, when I tail the log, right before the `Processing by CategoryController#show as HTML` line there is a `Cache read: https://edmundssite.com/wines/futures?` line.

I'm using the Dalli gem and memcache FYI.